# Почему медленно работает Wifi на компе? (на телефоне из этой же точки - быстро)

Tags: wifi, tp-link

Есть комп с вайфай адаптером TP-link archer t9e. Подключен к файфай. Тест скорости выдает 2-3мбита. Из этой же точки тест скорости с телефона(подключенного к этой же сети) выдает 20-30мбит.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### AC1900 Двухдиапазонный Wi-Fi адаптер PCI Express TP-link archer t9e

### Характеристики:

- Высокая скорость Wi-Fi - до 1900 Мбит/с (до 1300 Мбит/с на 5 ГГц или до 600 Мбит/с на 2,4 ГГц)
- Поддержка стандарта 802.11ac, скорость которого в 3 раза быстрее 802.11n - идеальное решение для выполнения ресурсоёмких задач

> Поддержка 5GHz здесь просто замануха. Если у вас
>   высокопроизводительное устройство то лучше поискать что-то другое. Так
>   как производитель намеренно заблокировал Каналы на российском рынке. И
>   получается, что если вам нужен 5GHz то вы просто потеряете в
>   производительности больше 50% потому что самые эффективные каналы с
>   которым данный адаптер работает просто заблокированы.

В отзывах прочитал еще:

> Как правило системные блоки стоят у стены и связь падает почти до нуля, пришлось развернуть блок антеннами в коридор.Слабовато ловит 5ГГц через стенку, до роутера (Airport Extreme AC) 6 метров. Скорость подключения 702 мБит, реальная раза в 3 меньше. При игре по сети теряются пакеты, и происходят зависания и обрывы (канал - оптика 200мБит). Приходится переключаться на 2,4ГГц вручную, там стабильно.
>   Установить непостердственно в PCI-E не получилось. Ситстема не видела адаптер, пришлось вставлять в PCIx16.

Comment: а ничего что вы приводите характеристики где написано `5ГГц` и дальше выдаете заключение, что адаптер старый и работает на `2.4` ?

Comment: @teran, вот поправил

Comment: *самые эффективные каналы с которым данный адаптер работает просто заблокированы* -- автор сего совершенно забывает о загруженности каналов другими сетями.

Comment: @D-side, тестировать надо

Comment: вот не пофиг на 5ГГц, если на 2.4 теоретически может быть до 600,как написано. а речь идет о том что бы получить хотя бы 20-30, а не 2-3

Comment: @олег, потестируйте, отодвиньте компьютер от стены, поднесите телефон к адаптеру компьютера и попробуйте запустить тест скорости, проверьте какая на телефоне частота потдерживается

Comment: @PavelBereznichenko это не ко мне.

Comment: @PavelBereznichenko спасибо! Дело оказалось в близости стены. Развернул системник антеннами от стены и стало 18мбит.